# Create file with egrep matches and file names

Tags: linux, shell

I need some help...

I'm creating a script of unit tests using shellscripts. That script, stores all the beeline calls from all files inside a directory.

The script is doing it's purpose, but I don't wanna append the file name if grep does not return results.

That's my code:

```
for file in $(ls)
do 
cat $file | egrep -on '^( +)?\bbeeline.*password=;"?' >> testa_scripts.sh
echo $file >> testa_scripts.sh 
done
```

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: That regex isn't guaranteed to work with `egrep` -- it has parts (like `\b`) that are PCRE, not ERE. See http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html for the specification of what *is* guaranteed to be supported in ERE proper, as referenced from http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html. Individual implementations may support extensions to the standard, but only what's documented is going to be reliably available across compliant platforms.

Comment: ...and btw, `for file in $(ls)` is [BashPitfalls #1](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#for_f_in_.24.28ls_.2A.mp3.29), and also the subject of [ParsingLs](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`grep` returns a falsy exit status (`1`) if it doesn't find any matching lines, so you can put in an `if` statement to test if it matched anything. Inverted with `!` here:

```
for file in ./*; do
    if ! egrep -on '...' "$file" >> somefile; then
        echo 'grep did not match anything'
    fi
done
```

<sub>(I don't think there's any need for the `ls` instead of just a shell glob here.)</sub>